# How to get the attributes created by the server when creating a model

Tags: backbone.js

For creating a new model I need to pass just one attribute:

```
model.save({
    name: 'bar'
});
```

Then the server will add extra attributes like the id for this model.

Actually the response of the server when I create the new model is

> this request has no response data available.

What is the best way to get the extra attributes created by the server?
Should I fix the sever part?

Here's my code:

```
var ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    // some code        

    events: {
        'click #create-user': 'createUser'
    },

    createUser: function (e) {
        this.collection.create(this.newAttributes(e));
    },

    newAttributes: function (e) {
        return {
            name: $(e.currentTarget).val(),
        };
    }

    appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
        collectionView.$el.find('ul.list-users').append(itemView.el);
    }

});
```

Comment: @RomainTribes the response of the server is: `this request has no response data available.`

Comment: Strange response. Your server should render some JSON to work well with Backbone Sync.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not related to Marionette, which only extends views, not models.

Backbone will automatically incorporate any new attributes sent back from the server - there is nothing special that needs to be done on the client side. But for this to work, your server needs to return a JSON object of attribute-value pairs that you want to be set.